# Creation of a matrix m x u from two data frames movies and users

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:
Movies:

```
    movie_id    Title                               Genres
0   1           Toy Story (1995)                    Animation|Children's|Comedy
1   2           Jumanji (1995)                      Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
2   3           Grumpier Old Men (1995)             Comedy|Romance
3   4           Waiting to Exhale (1995)            Comedy|Drama
4   5           Father of the Bride Part II (1995)  Comedy
```

Users:

```
    UserID  Gender  Age Occupation  Zip-code
0   1       F       1   10          48067
1   2       M       56  16          70072
2   3       M       25  15          55117
3   4       M       45  7           02460
4   5       M       25  20          55455
```

I need to create a m x u matrix with movies as rows and users as columns. I have been trying with pivot :
`s=movies.pivot(*users.columns)`. But am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-226654fd9a45> in <module>()
----> 1 s=movies.pivot(*ratings.columns)

TypeError: pivot() takes from 1 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Comment: You are unpacking your array, meaning that each of those column values becomes its own parameter. The ```pivot()``` function clearly requires the values to be as one parameter, so you might have to read the documentation for the input to get an idea of what it wants. Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html may provide some help.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that:

**m x u:**

```
>>> movies.join(users).set_index(movies.columns.tolist())

                                                                          UserID Gender  Age  Occupation  Zip-code
movie_id Title                              Genres                                                                
1        Toy Story (1995)                   Animation|Children's|Comedy        1      F    1          10     48067
2        Jumanji (1995)                     Adventure|Children's|Fantasy       2      M   56          16     70072
3        Grumpier Old Men (1995)            Comedy|Romance                     3      M   25          15     55117
4        Waiting to Exhale (1995)           Comedy|Drama                       4      M   45           7      2460
5        Father of the Bride Part II (1995) Comedy                             5      M   25          20     55455
```

**(m x u) x u:**

```
>>> pd.merge(users, movies, how='cross').set_index(movies.columns.tolist())

                                                                          UserID Gender  Age  Occupation  Zip-code
movie_id Title                              Genres                                                                
1        Toy Story (1995)                   Animation|Children's|Comedy        1      F    1          10     48067
2        Jumanji (1995)                     Adventure|Children's|Fantasy       1      F    1          10     48067
3        Grumpier Old Men (1995)            Comedy|Romance                     1      F    1          10     48067
4        Waiting to Exhale (1995)           Comedy|Drama                       1      F    1          10     48067
5        Father of the Bride Part II (1995) Comedy                             1      F    1          10     48067
1        Toy Story (1995)                   Animation|Children's|Comedy        2      M   56          16     70072
2        Jumanji (1995)                     Adventure|Children's|Fantasy       2      M   56          16     70072
3        Grumpier Old Men (1995)            Comedy|Romance                     2      M   56          16     70072
4        Waiting to Exhale (1995)           Comedy|Drama                       2      M   56          16     70072
5        Father of the Bride Part II (1995) Comedy                             2      M   56          16     70072
1        Toy Story (1995)                   Animation|Children's|Comedy        3      M   25          15     55117
2        Jumanji (1995)                     Adventure|Children's|Fantasy       3      M   25          15     55117
3        Grumpier Old Men (1995)            Comedy|Romance                     3      M   25          15     55117
4        Waiting to Exhale (1995)           Comedy|Drama                       3      M   25          15     55117
5        Father of the Bride Part II (1995) Comedy                             3      M   25          15     55117
1        Toy Story (1995)                   Animation|Children's|Comedy        4      M   45           7      2460
2        Jumanji (1995)                     Adventure|Children's|Fantasy       4      M   45           7      2460
3        Grumpier Old Men (1995)            Comedy|Romance                     4      M   45           7      2460
4        Waiting to Exhale (1995)           Comedy|Drama                       4      M   45           7      2460
5        Father of the Bride Part II (1995) Comedy                             4      M   45           7      2460
1        Toy Story (1995)                   Animation|Children's|Comedy        5      M   25          20     55455
2        Jumanji (1995)                     Adventure|Children's|Fantasy       5      M   25          20     55455
3        Grumpier Old Men (1995)            Comedy|Romance                     5      M   25          20     55455
4        Waiting to Exhale (1995)           Comedy|Drama                       5      M   25          20     55455
5        Father of the Bride Part II (1995) Comedy                             5      M   25          20     55455
```